# InternetOpen - first call slow on some machines

Tags: windows, winapi, delphi-xe5

I have an issue with an application that uses the wininet.dll function InternetOpen.

Simply put, on some machines, the first call to InternetOpenW takes a long time to return (20 to 60 seconds). 
On the other machines it is almost instantaneous.

This only happens Windows 7 machines so far, all the Windows 8 computers that I have tried it on don't have the issue, but I only have access to 3... The Windows 7 machines are all very similarly setup, although not quite identical: Windows 7 ultimate 64-bit, SP1, IE 11 (wininet.dll version 11.0.9600.17840). I have also checked the registry values for ProxyEnable, ProxyServer, and ProxyOverride (which InternetOpen checks, depending on parameter), and they match (besides, no proxies are used).

I have made sure all the machines are clean of viruses and malware. I have made sure the wininet.dll is the same version, compared the list of running Windows NT  services, tried from safe mode. No difference on the "affected" machines.

I'm fairly confident this hasn't got anything to do with the code itself. It is written in Delphi XE5. As a matter of fact, if I use some components that also call the InternetOpenW function, they exhibit the same issue on the affected machines.

Affected machines are affected all the time, "normal" machines always work fine.
IE itself does not appear slow on the affected machines.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO DAVID CHING**

Thanks for the hint. I installed Wireshark on both an affected and an unaffected machine and compared the results with a simple app that makes a HTTPS request to the maps.googleapi.com server.

I didn't notice any server hanging per se. However, there are some TCP packets to our network's external IP address. It's as if those calls, are delaying/blocking the application's traffic.

The strange thing is, the destination IP address is not in use at the moment - I use a Cisco rv320 router which allows for double WAN connections. The IP address is the backup internet service, but it's not connected to the router at the moment, and as a matter of fact, that connection is not setup at the moment, so the router doesn't (or at least shouldn't) know about it. That address has been used 3 weeks ago when our primary internet connection failed however (but the router was reconfigured after that).
Also, if the problem came from the router, I would expect all machines on the network to have the same issue, but it's not the case - wireshark captures from the "unaffected" machine don't show these packets (at least in the few seconds that I captured).

Here is a screen capture showing the TCP packets I'm mentioning:
[image]

Any ideas where to go from here, I'm no network expert I'm afraid.

Thanks!

Comment: Run Wireshark or MS Message Analyzer and see what servers are being accessed that need to timeout like that.

Comment: @David Ching: Thanks for the suggestion. I found some packets that seem "weird" to me (see my edit), but I've no idea how to go about fixing it, or if it's even related. Any ideas?

Comment: Open the Internet Settings in Control Panel on an affected machine and see if a proxy is being set to your backup site. These settings are used by both WinInet and IE. Very strange IE is never affected though.

Comment: @David Ching: Nope, no proxy set there. I've even reset the entire options, reverted to IE 8 and upgraded back, going through each version of IE until IE 11. Puzzled...

Comment: You can use [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to see the WinInet and lower level API's being called by your app and compare them to how IE is calling them.  Maybe you need to call [InternetSetOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to set some connection specific setting.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out the issue was related to IPv6 on my network. Not sure why, but the wininet call on some machines tries IPv6 first, only falls back on IPv4 if IPv6 fails.

Our ISP doesn't support Ipv6, so of course those first attempts failed.

Thanks to David Ching for pointing me to the tools that led to the discovery :o)

Comment: Actually, I haven't figured that part out yet. For now, since my ISP doesn't support IPv6, I simply turned off the DHCP-IPv6 service on my router, as well as the Dual-Stack IP option (I use a Cisco RV320). That's enough for now, although it doesn't seem that elegant to me.
I have read about a few settings regarding routing priorities, I'll run tests on those. I'll leave an update :o)